# Code for Bluetooth Low Energy connecting with API > 23

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm making EMG signal android application using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

When I build my code on `API<=23` phone, it can scan devices. But when I build it on `API>23`, it can't scan any devices. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you better describe what "can't scan any devices" means? Do you get a compilation error? Does it crash at run-time? Does it run but not behave as expected? Please edit your question and provide more details (error message, expected behaviour, effective behaviour).

Comment: And please add the code relevant for scanning as well.